# Call CPLEX from PHP

Tags: php, cplex

I need to make my PHP app cooperate with CPLEX Solver. The good news is I'm familiar with LP, but the bad news is I haven't used CPLEX until now. From the documentation I can see that using CPLEX is fairly easy through the integrated IDE, or via default C, JAVA, C#, Python APIs or a callable library API. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any examples at all of CPLEX being used from PHP.

1. Is such a thing even possible? I know I can execute any bash command through `exec`, but CPLEX often requires several interactive steps to be performed to solve a single problem, and I don'g know how to do that from PHP;
2. If answer to 1. is 'yes', can anyone share even a simple example of how it can be done? I.e. a PHP script that calls CPLEX to resolve an LP problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't likely be any ready made examples because there is only a callable lib for C and an API for C++, Java and C#.  There is also a separate Python API.

You could potentially use Gearman or write a REST wrapper in Python that your PHP app could consume.

Alternatively you could write your own PHP extension that wraps the C functions you need to call.  Not sure if you can precisely what you need to do with [Zephir](https://docs.zephir-lang.com/en/latest/optimizers.html) but you could have a look - it's really simple to get started with...